# What does :global (colon global) do?

Tags: css, css-modules

In some SCSS files, I see the following:

```
:global {
  /* ... */
}
```

I don't know if it is an SCSS feature or a CSS feature.
I tried searching about it but couldn't find any good results at first sight.

Comment: Looks like they are using CSS-modules: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: @Pete to be fair, it's not exactly easy to search for. Google won't search for `:global`, you need to play with keywords a bit to end up on the CSS Modules page.

Comment: It's really hard search about that, there are few results and nothing explanation. I was found this: https://medium.com/seek-developers/the-end-of-global-css-90d2a4a06284 . Interesting and very future proof.

Comment: The 2 downvotes are unmeritory

Comment: You must have found this somewhere. If it's a file, it should have a file extension that tells you whether it's SASS or LESS. If it's an article on the internet, I presume it'll have a title or appropriate tags. You haven't shared that with us so we have less information than you.

Comment: @Pete I saw that too, and initially skipped them because I (wrongly) assumed they weren't what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pete depending on your region and search engine. Look at this screenshot: https://s1.postimg.org/pgtn62srj/Captura_de_pantalla_2017-04-25_a_las_16.55.34.png . Except the link I've attached on the previous comment, the rest of results are not related with `:global`.

Comment: I know google can't search ":global" string, I tryied with symbolhound.com, but I can't find answer for me. Thanks @Troyer, now I know it's is a feature of css preprocessor (css-module). It isn't a css selector similar :root. Do I understand right?

Comment: @wellbeck190 If my answer was the correct one please mark it as correct answer, thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for spelling out "colon" in your question title, I was looking for the colon rather than "global" per se and it allowed me to find your question.  Something I'll try to do in my own Q&As.

Answer (score 115):

The `:global` operator is used in [CSS Modules](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/what-are-css-modules/). Modular CSS uses a CSS Modules compiler to scope CSS styles within their respective modules (e.g., React component).

Here's an example from a React module (in the file `ErrorMessaging.less` for the `ErrorMessaging.jsx` React component):

```
:global(.ocssContainer) {
  .ui_column {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

This gets compiled into:

```
  .ErrorMessaging__alertContainer--1I-Cz .ocssContainer .ErrorMessaging__ui_column--3uMUS {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
```

But now I add a `:global` modifier onto `.ui_column`:

```
:global(.ocssContainer) {
  :global(.ui_column) {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

And this is what it compiles to:

```
  .ErrorMessaging__alertContainer--1I-Cz .ocssContainer .ui_column {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
```

Now `.ui_column` can apply to any child element with that style, including in a child React component, and not just `.ui_column` elements that are part of the `ErrorMessaging` React component.

Comment: well written with examples

Comment: To clarify a bit more.. you can even use ".ErrorMessaging > :global(.ui_column) { ... }" in the module.. this will hash the parent class, but the child will be a global one

Answer (score 26):

It looks like they are using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). If you follow the docs they say:

> :global switches to global scope for the current selector resp.
>   identifier. :global(.xxx) resp. @keyframes :global(xxx) declares the
>   stuff in parenthesis in the global scope.

Comment: I don't get what the above paragraph means

I read the paragraph in 2 parts
This is the first part:
:global switches to global scope for the current selector resp. identifier. :global(.xxx) resp.

And this is the second part:
@keyframes :global(xxx) declares the stuff in parenthesis in the global scope.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @gaurav5430 Easy way to understand it is that whatever is `:global( here )` won't be mangled by the CSS modules compiler. So `:global(.foobar)` in `something.modules.css` will be output in final CSS as `.foobar`, while `.foobar` will be converted into a more or less random string (depending on how the CSS modules compiler is configured), like `._1mHzwvK6Zff6h4llp7BPKK`.

Comment: @Svish should put your comment as an answer, i read the two answers, but they do not mention the key word `mangled`

Answer (score 5):

The `:global` selector keyword is used in css modules to specify that a class should not be scoped to the component in which it is defined. This selector allows the class to be used globally in the application, rather than just within a specific component. For example, let say you have a `.is-global-class` class defined in a CSS Module file, you can use `:global(.is-global-class)` to apply that class to an element and make it available globally.