# What does this mixin mean?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

In a scss file, I saw the below code snippet:

```
@mixin myMixin() {
    :global(.rtl) & {
        @content;
    }
}
```

I understand the keywords `@mixin`as well as `@content` and tried to understand `:global()` from this link:
 [What does :global (colon global) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613619/what-does-global-colon-global-do).

But I am not sure what "&" does here or what this whole mixin does.

Comment: Can you post the code where the mixin is `@include`

Comment: It’s webpack related. Matches global classes. A quick google search will show some nice examples.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (&) is a combinator used in nesting and in this case it is being used to qualify a selector.

For a general example:

```
// This Sass...
.foo {
  .bar & {
    color: red;
  }
}

// ...would compile to this CSS
.bar .foo { color:red; }
```

In your example, the mixin declaration replaces `.foo`, and would look like:

```
// If you called your mixin at .bar
.bar {
  @include myMixin {
    color: red;
  }
}

// It should compile to something like this
:global(.rtl) .bar { color: red; }
```

More details about [ampersands and qualifying selectors in this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-5).