# How do I override the styles in ant-design 5?

Tags: css, sass, antd, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm using React (create-react-app), **ant design 5.3.0** and **modular scss**.

When using embedded components, their styles override mine, because the component creates a wrapper and my styles are hung from the upstream wrapper and the downstream element creates the ant design itself.

To override them in scss, I figured out that I need to declare an inline class inside my class which generates ant design. For example, for Typography it will form .ant-typography.
There's one BUT: if you don't use modular scss (don't write to files like head.module.css), you're fine. **And if you write in *modular scss* files, it doesn't override.**

[Head.module.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyk8L.jpg)
[index.js importing module scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhLnG.jpg)  [what render index.js with module scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAg8n.jpg)
[index.js importing plain scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53h5t.jpg)  [what render index.js with plain scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nmj0.jpg)
(sorry: i dont have enough reputation to post images yet because of novice contributor)

I think it has something to do with kebab-case notation. I tried changing the notation to camelCase in the model files, but that didn't help either. Can you tell me how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
:global(.className) {
    // Set CSS Properties
}
```

in the modular scss file

For example:

```
:global(.swiper-pagination) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Inspect the page to find the classname you need to override.
Here's a link about ':global':
[What does :global (colon global) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613619/what-does-global-colon-global-do)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was helpful for me.

But I used following approach:


:global {
    .swiper-pagination {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


Is it the same like yours?

Comment: @Evgeniy S. I think both approaches do the same thing. And you can also try using ':local {...}' if you do not want to define your style in global scope.