# How can I force Astro to render my markdown with scoped classes within a component?

Tags: css, components, markdown, astrojs

I have an Astro component in which I'm rendering markdown to html (with `@astropub/md`), and then trying to target the rendered markdown with scoped CSS within the component.

However, the css scoping is expecting classes that are not being rendered by `@astropub/md`.

Ex:

```
---
import { markdown } from "@astropub/md";
---

<p>this text is not bold, <strong>but this is</strong>.</p>
{markdown("this text is not bold, **but this is**.")}
<style>
   strong {
      color: red;
   }
</style>
```

This will effectively render like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
  strong:where(.astro-UW5KDBXL){
    color:red
  }
</style>
<p class="astro-UW5KDBXL">
  this text is not bold, <strong class="astro-UW5KDBXL">but this is</strong>.
</p>
<p>
  this text is not bold, <strong>but this is</strong>.
</p>
```

The example that is rendered from markdown is missing the classes that the scoped `style` definitions are using to color the text.

I've added the markdown package to my astro.config.mjs integrations, but that doesn't seem to change how it renders the markdown.

I can use `<style is:inline` or `<style is:global>`, but then I lose the scoped nature, and I feel like that would defeat one of the advantages of Astro's 'island' structure.

So how do I force `astropub/md` to render the scoped classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:global` CSS selector to apply the styles to child elements of that component.

```
---
import { markdown } from "@astropub/md";
---

<p>this text is not bold, <strong>but this is</strong>.</p>
{markdown("this text is not bold, **but this is**.")}
<style>
   :global(strong) {
      color: red;
   }
</style>
```

- More info about [global styles](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#global-styles) in Astro
- [What does `:global` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52895247/14104186) - SO Answer

Comment: Oh, that's perfect.  Even works when I need to get more specific with my declarations: `p :global(strong) { color: var(--teal); }`.