# How to override React Bootstrap active Tab default border styling

Tags: css, reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap, styling

I'm attempting to override the default border styling (width and color) of my React Bootstrap Tabs component.  The part that I'm having difficulty with in particular is the active Tab.   This image shows an example of the border that I'm trying to manipulate:
[image]

Below is an example of the code that I'm working with:

```
<div>
    <Tabs
        className="customTabs"
        eventKey="example-key"
        onSelect={selected => onTabSelect(selected)}
        >
        <Tab
            title="a"
            eventKey="tab1"
            />
        <Tab
            title="b"
            eventKey="tab2"
            />

    </Tabs>
</div>
 
// Styling using Sass

.customTabs {
    li.active {
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }
}
```

Based on the developer tools the border that I'm interested in changing seems to be: .nav-tabs > li.active (nav-tabs being the default bootstrap class).

Any suggestions on how I might go about overriding this?

Currently, I've tried the above in addition to  li.active > a, .nav > li.active...  I've also used an id selector in addition to class selector.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the fact that we are using [CSS modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613619/what-does-global-colon-global-do), therefore I needed to use :global.  The trickier part was making sure that my child borders overlay-ed the parent borders.

```
:global {

.nav-tabs {

    opacity: 0.8;

    border-bottom: 2px solid black;

    li {

        a {

            margin-right: 0;

            background: white;

        }

        &.active {

            border: 2px solid black;

            border-bottom: transparent;

            a {

                margin-bottom: -1px;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

}